# I got my iPhone back from service with a sticker on "WMI Fail" or "VMI Fail". What is "WMI"/"VMI"?

Tags: iphone, ios, warranty, applecare

I just got my iPhone back from service with a sticker on "WMI Fail".

What is "WMI"?

Googling doesn't return any sensible Apple related explanation, neither does asking @AppleSupport on Twitter (they didn't know).

Comment: Why don't you ask the people who put the sticker on it? WMI would usually be [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx) but I have no clue why that would be relevant to an iPhone

Comment: I have asked both Apple Assistance and AppleCare. They couldn't answer!

Comment: Any chance this refers to water damage being detected?

Comment: @TomGewecke It wasn't the reason I sent the phone to service but of course, I can't rule it out, I have used the phone in rain etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a second answer now. It might be that I mixed up V and W (the sticker fell off more or less immediately after I got the phone back): VMI = Visual Mechanical Inspection.

Answer (score 1):

By coincidence I met someone who works with this and he told that *WMI* was an acronym for *Warranty Mechanical Inspection*. He was "pretty" sure about this although but not completely sure (first he misunderstood me and thought I said *VMI* which he explained as *Visual Mechanical Inspection* - I guess "Mechanical Inspection" for MI is a safe bet at least).

If someone could confirm/refute this it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

WMI is not a well-known acronym in this business (iPhones). There's no specific part in your iPhone which is known as the "WMI".

For all we know, WMI could be the initials of the guy repairing it at the service center - or it could be "WIFI" written in bad handwriting.

Comment: It was a preprinted sticker so my conclusion is that it is a common factor/result or similar. I have written a (paper) letter to Apple to ask about this now. Will post here if/when I receive an answer.